# Issues Running JSON File in Python Environment and Setting up NLP Project

Tags: python, json, nlp, virtualenv

I am having issues figuring out how to complete a beginner NLP chatbot. I created a JSON file within my Python virtual environment, though it seems I am unable to confirm if the file is being utilized properly. Please help me figure out how to import the JSON file and well as determine which tools I can utilize to best complete my project.

The tutorial I am following instructs me to do the following in the Jupyter notes:

How to import our chat-bot intents file-

```
import json
with open('intents.json') as json_data:
    intents = json.load(json_data)
```

Per my Python interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 17 2018, 19:45:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> with open('chatbotIntents.json') as json_data:
...     intents = json.load(json_data)
...
```

I believe I would be performing this action utilizing the Python interpreter, correct? When I have done this, the interpreter seems to be anticipating more code to follow and I seem receive no feedback as to whether the request is completed.

The tutorial continues by demonstrating python code in the Jupyter notebook, but I've only used the Python interpreter for single lines of code thusfar. To organize the documents, words and classification classes in my NLP project, would you all recommend running my code in Jupyter on my mac to run the code as I follow along the tutorial? Are there any other alternatives you all would suggest?

Link to tutorial and notebooks: https://chatbotsmagazine.com/contextual-chat-bots-with-tensorflow-4391749d0077

Answer (score 0):

> I believe I would be performing this action utilizing the Python interpreter, correct?

Yes.

> When I have done this, the interpreter seems to be anticipating more code to follow and I seem receive no feedback as to whether the request is completed.

This is because in programming silence is often the Ok/Yes answer. The interpreter didn't raise an error hence everything is ok and you can continue,

> would you all recommend

That part of your question is not suitable for StackOverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking